# Renaming or Moving WP-Content Pros/Cons

Tags: wp-query

I'm still learning WP. Previously I had done a 1-click installation of WP. Everything worked fine. But now, I'm planning to install it manually.

What are the Pros/Cons of these?

1 Renaming wp-content

(I have heard some plugins won't work. Could I maybe just rename wp-content in the plugin code?)

2 Moving wp-content or wp-uploads
Any harm in doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to? Although you can do this in theory, in practice a lot of plugins aren't written in a way that handles this. Unless you have a reason for doing this, don't.

Comment: it's just for enhancing security and prevent bot attacks. do you have any experience regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend installing WordPress manually yourself. Some companies will insert a link crediting the hosting provider for the install. In the past, I've experienced 1-click installations that are not running the latest version of WordPress.

In terms of migrating your website, you should follow this guide: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress. Smashing Magazine also provide an easy tutorial: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website.

In a nutshell, you'll download the whole site via an FTP (including the WordPress core files, plugin folders, uploads and your themes) and then transfer these files to the new server. Using something like phpMyAdmin, you'll need to export the old database, create a new database on the new server and then import the data. You'll find all the information you need in the links I've provided.

---

**Update**

In the comments @Dan has suggested this article in the codex for those who wish to move the wp-content directory: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder.

@Brijesh This article explains the benefits of moving your wp-content folder and gives you detailed instructions: http://www.paulund.co.uk/move-wp-content-folder-to-different-location.

Comment: you didn't answer my question!

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you'd like to install WordPress yourself. I have given you instructions for making your first migration and indicated the benefits of installing WordPress yourself. You should never rename the wp-content directory, adjust core plugin files or move the wp-content / wp-uploads directories. Doing so would prevent you from updating to new versions of WordPress or plugins. If I have misunderstood your question, please edit it.

Comment: @Squideyes, that is not correct. You can modify the name of those directories, though plugins don't always handle this correctly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder

Comment: My bad @Dan. Thank you for pointing this out. I personally like to maintain the core structure.